# CZ-gate in neutral atoms computer with Rydberg pulses

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-state, quantum-operation

I'm trying to understand the protocol to obtain a CZ-Gate with two qubits and Rydberg pulses : https://queracomputing.github.io/Bloqade.jl/dev/3-level/#pulse-CZ-gate

1. Apply Rydberg π-pulse on control qubit
2. Apply Rydberg 2π-pulse on target qubit
3. Apply Rydberg π-pulse on control qubit

I understand that applying a π-pulse put a qubit into the Rydberg State and if it was already in Rydberg State it put it back in ground state. I also understand the Rydberg blockade effect where two qubits close to each other can't be in the Rydberg State at the same time.

What I don't understand is :

- What does the 2π-pulse do here ?
- What does it change if I apply a pulse on a qubit which was in the ground state |0> or |1> ?

Or if someone could explain to me from A to Z how this protocol apply a CZ-Gate on the entangled qubits |00>, |01>, |10> and |11>

Answer (score 1):

If you apply a $2\pi$ rotation to a single qubit, it picks up a global phase, often called a geometric phase:

$$U_{2\pi}|\psi\rangle=e^{-i2\pi(\sigma_x/2)}|\psi\rangle = -|\psi\rangle$$

where $\sigma_x$ is one of the Pauli matrices. In your problem, $\sigma_x = |r\rangle\langle 1| + |1\rangle \langle r|$.

Global phases are not physically measurable, but *relative* phases are. In the Rydberg gate, the Rydberg blockade prevents the $2\pi$ rotation on the target qubit, so the $|01\rangle$ state picks up a phase, but the $|11\rangle$ state experiences the blockade. This prevents the second qubit from undergoing the $2\pi$ rotation, and therefore we don't get any phase.

To work this out, let $|\psi\rangle = a|00\rangle+b|01\rangle+c|10\rangle+d|11\rangle$. Here's what happens:

- $\pi$ pulse on control qubit: $|\psi\rangle \rightarrow a|00\rangle+b|01\rangle+c|r0\rangle+d|r1\rangle$
- $2\pi$ pulse on the target qubit: $\rightarrow a|00\rangle-b|01\rangle+c|r0\rangle+d|r1\rangle$
- $\pi$ pulse on control qubit: $\rightarrow a|00\rangle-b|01\rangle+c|10\rangle+d|11\rangle$

The magic is in the second step. Because we picked up a phase conditional on the state of both qubits together (had to be specifically in $|01\rangle$), we have created entanglement.

Comment: How do you know that the Pauli matrice is that ? And why is it |1> and not |0> ?

Comment: It's all just arbitrary convention/choices. By definition the Pauli X matrix is $|0\rangle\langle1|+|1\rangle\langle0|$, which flips $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$. The one I wrote is just defining a Pauli matrix on a certain transition. But we could just as well have used the Pauli Y matrix, and in fact the Hamiltonian at the top of the page you linked allows for X, Y or anything in between (try plugging in $\phi_i^r=0$ and $\phi_i^r = \pi/2$; $\phi_i^r=0$ gives what I wrote).

Comment: As for why it's $|1\rangle\langle r|+|r\rangle\langle 1|$ instead of $|0\rangle\langle r|+|r\rangle\langle 0|$, that's the convention chosen in the Hamiltonian at the top of your link. The term $\Omega_i^r$ drives the $|1\rangle$ to $|r\rangle$ transition.

Comment: Thank you it explains a lot ! One last question, I thought CZ-gate only affected |11> state ? Why is it |01> which is affected here ?

Comment: Well maybe there's a more clever way to apply the phase directly to $|11\rangle$, but this is what you get with the simplest scheme. You can turn it into a CZ gate by pi-pulsing the first qubit. The linked webpage also mentions this.